# Basic plugin analysis failed "class not extends the Plugin class"

Tags: shopware6

I created a plugin (for Shopware 6) and I'm having some trouble having it validated on the basic extension analysis. I'm getting the following feedback:

> Basic plugin analysis failed.
> the class not extends the Plugin class

(I'm uploading a zip file with a folder, with the plugin/technical name, and the plugin inside (`PLUGIN NAME/src/...`)

Here's my plugin class

```
<?php
    namespace Lorem\IpsumDolor;

    class LoremIpsumDolor extends \Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin{

        //Executing composer commands during plugin installation
        public function executeComposerCommands(): bool{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:
Here's my plugin `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "lorem/dolor-ipsum",
    "description": "...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "shopware-platform-plugin",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Tony",
            "role": "Manufacturer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "shopware/core": ">=6.0.0",
        "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.13.9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Lorem\\IpsumDolor\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/runtime": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does the composer.json of the plugin looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Plugin base guide.
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-base-guide

You're missing the "extra" part in your composer.json in which the "shopware-plugin-class" information is placed.

```
{
  "name": "lorem/dolor-ipsum",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "shopware-platform-plugin",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Tony",
      "role": "Manufacturer"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "shopware/core": ">=6.0.0",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.13.9"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Lorem\\IpsumDolor\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "symfony/runtime": true
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "shopware-plugin-class": "Lorem\\IpsumDolor\\LoremIpsumDolor",
    "label": {
      "en-GB": "The displayed readable name for the plugin"
    },
    "description": {
      "en-GB": "Description in the Administration for this plugin"
    }
  }
}
```

And you should probably import the plugin class

```
<?php
    namespace Lorem\IpsumDolor;

    use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin;

    class LoremIpsumDolor extends Plugin {

        //Executing composer commands during plugin installation
        public function executeComposerCommands(): bool{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Done but the issue remains.